# Remove javascript comments from html erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried using both uglifier and terser for removing the comments by passing below code one by one and restarted the server as well

```
config.assets.debug = false

// 1st attempt
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true, output: { comments: :none })

// 2nd attempt
config.assets.js_compressor = Terser.new({output: { comments: :none }})

// 3rd attempt
config.assets.js_compressor = Terser.new(output: { comments: :none })
```

**My code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // remove this comment
  let x = 1;
  console.log(x);
</script>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
  // remove this comment
  <!-- hi there -->
  let y = 2;
  console.log(y);
<% end %>
```

**Output html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // remove this comment
  let x = 1;
  console.log(x);
</script>

<script>
//<![CDATA[

  // remove this comment
  <!-- remove this comment -->
  let y = 2;
  console.log(y);

//]]>
</script>
```

All the js code are getting executed. Is this possible with the current js_compressors ?
What is wrong here ?

Comment: Believe that both of these only work on files in the assets -- not in the erb files.

Comment: So the only option to remove comments is to use something like this

'<script type="text/javascript"><%= raw Uglifier.new.compile(render "path_to_asset_file.js") %><script>'

Comment: Or just put all your javascript in javascript files